# WPF: ICommand, open a txt file in textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, icommand

I have a little problem here , I have to open (read) a text file in a basic WPF notepad kind thing , but i have to do with ICommand interface. The problem is that when i chose the txt file i want to open , nothings happen, I just see an empty notepad. There is any solution for this? Here is the code:

```
    public class OpenCommand : ICommand
{

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();

        op.Filter = "textfile|*.txt";
        op.DefaultExt = "txt";
        if(op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

            File.ReadAllText(op.FileName);

        }

    }
}
```

Maybe the bindig is not i really don't know at this point.

```
                <MenuItem Header="File" >
                <MenuItem Header="New"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Open..." Command="{Binding MyOpenCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=textbox2, Path=Text}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Save..." Command="{Binding MySaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=textbox2, Path=Text}"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Exit..." Command="{Binding MyExitCommand}"/>

            </MenuItem>
```

There is the binding, i want the see the file in the "textbox2"

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox2" DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
             Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
             AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

Comment: you haven't assigned `File.ReadAllText(op.FileName);` result to any variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the `TextBox` to the content of the text file.

The following example uses the reusable `RelayCommand` which accepts a delegate. This makes passing of the result to the binding source more elegant.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ICommand OpenCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteOpemFile);
  public ICommand ExitCommand => new RelayCommand(param => Application.Current.MainWindow.Close());

  private string textFileContent;   
  public string TextFileContent
  {
    get => this.textFileContent;
    set 
    { 
      this.textFileContent= value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public ExecuteOpemFile(object commandParameter)
  {
    OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
    op.Filter = "textfile|*.txt";
    op.DefaultExt = "txt";

    if(op.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
      this.TextFileContent = File.ReadAllText(op.FileName);
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**
Implementation copied from [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic).

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
  #region Fields

  readonly Action<object> _execute;
  readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

  #endregion // Fields 

  #region Constructors

  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
  {
  }

  public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
  {
    if (execute == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
  }

  #endregion // Constructors 

  #region ICommand Members

  [DebuggerStepThrough]
  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
  }

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
  }

  public void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    _execute(parameter);
  }

  #endregion // ICommand Members 
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <Menu>
      <MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
      <MenuItem Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
    </Menu>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextFileContent}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: I did it but when i use the Open MenuItem nothing happens, i mean the dialog appears, and i can choose the txt i want to open, but it nothing happens it didnd appear in the textbox

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce it. For me it works. Please check if you have any typos in your binding. Run the application in debug mode to see if you encounter any exception. Make sure the file is not empty.